# GIT/Xcode : How to commit without send a personal library

Tags: iphone, xcode, git, svn

I'm looking for a solution for commit/push any changes in my Xcode project without sharing my custom library sources.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: Bit light on details, but if you are just referencing the compiled libraries, then will including the compiled library files suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want to commit/push all your project's code except some custom libraries. If you didn't do anything yet, just don't add those files to the project. If they were already added, just ignore them (check [this](http://help.github.com/ignore-files/))